# Throw object vs throw variable as exception in c++ oop

Tags: c++, exception

I have been reading a book where the object oriented implementation for exceptions is as follows:

> Rectangle.hpp

```
class Rectangle
{
private:
    // code

public:
    class NegativeSize
    {
        // empty class declaration
        // for exception
    };

    // code
};
```

Whenever a specific error occurs, the NegativeSize() is thrown from the constructor as follows:

> Rectangle.cpp

```
void Rectangle::setX(int _x)
{
    if (_x < 0)
    {
        // this instantiates an object
        throw NegativeSize();
    }

    x = _x;
}
```

> main.cpp

```
    try
    {
        // code
    }
    catch (Rectangle::NegativeSize)
    {
        cout << "Negative value entered" << endl;
    }
```

But I can do the same thing by declaring a public variable in Rectangle class and throw it instead:

> Rectangle.hpp

```
class Rectangle
{
private:
    // code

public:
    string NegativeVal;

    // code
};
```

> Rectangle.cpp

```
void Rectangle::setX(int _x)
{
    if (_x < 0)
    {
        throw NegativeSize;
    }

    x = _x;
}
```

> main.cpp

```
    try
    {
        // code
    }
    catch (string NegativeSize)
    {
        cout << "Negative value entered" << endl;
    }
```

Can the second implementation be considered a good practice?

Comment: do you mean `throw negativeVal` in your second example?

Comment: No, it's not a good practice.  The first isn't either, since the object being thrown doesn't derive from `std::exception`.

Comment: It makes no real difference.   Whether the object thrown previously exists or is initialised at the throw point, it may be *copied* an arbitrary number of times during stack unwinding.    Either way, having an exception object with a member that has constructors which may throw, is bad practice since it can result in a second exception being thrown during stack unwinding.   Although not technically necessary, it is also considered good style to derive exceptions from `std::exception` (or from a class derived from `std::exception`).

Comment: I'm having trouble getting your second example to compile, which is a prerequisite for being good practice. If I leave it as-is, the compiler complains that `NegativeSize` is not defined. If I change both `NegativeSize`s to `NegativeVal` (as implied by the text), the compiler complains on the `catch` line `'NegativeVal' in 'class Rectangle' does not name a type`. What is the actual code you propose for the second implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual exception object that the `catch` clause will catch is not the object that you name or refer to in the `throw` expression. Instead the exception object is an object of the same (decayed) type as the `throw` operand and initialized from the same.

So in your first example you throw an object of type `Rectangle::NegativeSize` which is initialized from `NegativeSize()` and in the second example you throw a `std::string` which is a copy of the `NegativeSize` member, whatever value it holds at that time.

In the second example `catch (Rectangle::NegativeSize)` will not work, because `NegativeSize` is not a type anymore. You will need to catch `std::string` instead, which of course is a problem, since it doesn't tell you at all what the kind of exception this is (plus some other deeper issues).

Throwing a `std::string` instead of a specific exception class is therefore not a good practice. You wouldn't be able to differentiate different exceptions and catch only those you can handle in a given `catch` clause.

Throwing a data member also seems pointless. What value will you set it to? Probably just the `"Negative value entered"` string? If so, that could be thrown directly as `throw std::string("Negative value entered");` as well. As I said above, the exception object is going to be a copy anyway. At the `catch` clause you can't identify anymore that the `throw` expression used the `NegativeSize` member.

Also, in practice exception classes are usually derived from `std::exception` or a class derived from it and are not empty. They commonly store a string which can be given at the point of the `throw` expression, so that detailed information from the source of the exception can be provided to the user, e.g.:

```
class Rectangle
{
private:
    // code

public:
    struct NegativeSize : std::invalid_argument {};

    // code
};

//...

void Rectangle::setX(int _x)
{
    if (_x < 0)
    {
        throw NegativeSize("Negative value entered");
    }

    x = _x;
}

//...

try
{
    // code
}
catch (const Rectangle::NegativeSize& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Also, as I do above, exceptions should usually be caught by-reference.